# How to join two dataframes base the words exist in them when they are not equal?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have 2 datasets, which contain unique values. The first one, which is the one below has the full name of a few hospitals.

```
+-----------------------+
| HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL    |
+-----------------------+
| St. Christine         |
| Californian Hospital  |
| Holy Mercy Hospital   |
| Germanic NW Hospital  |
| Trauma Center Hospital|
| Holy Spirit Hospital  |
| Mater Hospital        |
+-----------------------+
```

The other one has the short name of the same hospitals above.

```
+---------------------+
| HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT |
+---------------------+
| Christine           |
| Californian         |
| Mercy               |
| Germanic            |
| Trauma              |
| Holy                |
| Mater               |
+---------------------+
```

The thing is, I need to join them, so I can have both full name and short name. Can I join dataframes while using some kind of regex so I can have this result?

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+ 
| HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL    | HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
| St. Christine         | Christine           |
| Californian Hospital  | Californian         |
| Holy Mercy Hospital   | Mercy               |
| Germanic NW Hospital  | Germanic            |
| Trauma Center Hospital| Trauma              |
| Holy Spirit Hospital  | Holy                |
| Mater Hospital        | Mater               |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR,** If your words in `HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT` exactly exist in `HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL` I recommend the first approach and if you want to consider similarity between words, I recommend second approach:

**First Approach:** *(word exactly exist)*

```
df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT'] = df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL'].apply(
    lambda x: next(st for st in df2['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT'] if st in x))

print(df1)
```

**Second Approach** *(consider Similarty)*

You can use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) and find similarities between each two words from two dataframes and return a word that have max similarity for each row:

*What is `difflib.SequenceMatcher`:*

```
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, 'Vitamin_A', 'Vitamin_C').ratio()
0.8888888888888888
```

Solving this problem with `SequenceMatcher`:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT'] = df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL'].apply(
    lambda x: max([(st, SequenceMatcher(None, x, st).ratio()) 
                   for st in df2['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT']], key=lambda x: x[1])[0])

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
       HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT
0           St. Christine           Christine
1    Californian Hospital         Californian
2     Holy Mercy Hospital               Mercy
3    Germanic NW Hospital            Germanic
4  Trauma Center Hospital              Trauma
5    Holy Spirit Hospital                Holy
6          Mater Hospital               Mater
```

Input two dataframe:

```
print(df1)
#        HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL
# 0           St. Christine
# 1    Californian Hospital
# 2     Holy Mercy Hospital
# 3    Germanic NW Hospital
# 4  Trauma Center Hospital
# 5    Holy Spirit Hospital
# 6          Mater Hospital

print(df2)
#   HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT
# 0           Christine
# 1         Californian
# 2               Mercy
# 3            Germanic
# 4              Trauma
# 5                Holy
# 6               Mater
```

Comment: Note the warning in the [`Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) docs recommending use of `to_numpy()` instead.

Comment: In fact, in this case I think you can use the Series directly in your list comprehension with no method call (see my answer, for example).

Comment: @constantstranger, you are right, I'm too fast for sending and don't consider

Answer (score 2):

You can try `.str.extract`

```py
df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT'] = df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(df2['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT'])+')')
```

```
print(df1)

       HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT
0           St. Christine           Christine
1    Californian Hospital         Californian
2     Holy Mercy Hospital                Holy
3    Germanic NW Hospital            Germanic
4  Trauma Center Hospital              Trauma
5    Holy Spirit Hospital                Holy
6          Mater Hospital               Mater
```

You can also consider `str.extractall` to show to all possible matches

```py
df1 = (df1
       .join(
           df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL'].str.extractall('('+'|'.join(df2['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT'])+')')
           .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
       )
)
```

```
print(df1)

       HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL            0      1
0           St. Christine    Christine    NaN
1    Californian Hospital  Californian    NaN
2     Holy Mercy Hospital         Holy  Mercy
3    Germanic NW Hospital     Germanic    NaN
4  Trauma Center Hospital       Trauma    NaN
5    Holy Spirit Hospital         Holy    NaN
6          Mater Hospital        Mater    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
df1['HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT'] = df1.HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL.apply(lambda x: [y for y in df2.HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT if y in x][0])
```

Output:

```
       HOSPITAL_NAME_FULL HOSPITAL_NAME_SHORT
0           St. Christine           Christine
1    Californian Hospital         Californian
2     Holy Mercy Hospital               Mercy
3    Germanic NW Hospital            Germanic
4  Trauma Center Hospital              Trauma
5    Holy Spirit Hospital                Holy
6          Mater Hospital               Mater
```